# When adding a random edge to a graph, which bridge edges are not bridge edges any longer?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

A random edge *e* is added to a graph. It happens to not be a bridge edge. Let *C* be the connected component of the endpoints of *e*.

Given the list *L* of all the bridge edges of *C* (before *e* was added), which is the fastest algorithm to find which edges in *L* are still bridge edges after the insertion of *e*?

Comment: At most one former bridge will no longer be a bridge. Assuming the two endpoints were only one-connected before the insertion,  the bridge that is no longer one is the edge that is part of every path from one endpoint to another, pre-insertion. You can find that  in O(|C| + #edges in C) using DFS, for example, using a slight variation of the regular bridge-finding algorithm

Comment: @NiklasB. What does it mean that the two endpoints were only one-connected before the insertion?

Comment: Are you allowed to pre-process the graph?

Comment: @amit Yes, you can preprocess as much as you want, and then edges start appearing and disappearing. Here I am considering the particular case in which an edge appears and is not a bridge edge. I've got all the other cases covered. I mention this because if you want to propose data structures, they should be adaptable to edge removals as well.

Comment: @Niklas B.: There can be more than one edge that is no longer a bridge. In an n-cycle, there are no bridges, but removing one edge would make every edge a bridge.

Comment: @Douglas good point, I was thinking DAGs. Nevermind

Comment: Well in any case, before adding an edge (x, y) within the same connected component, you can do a traversal of the CC to find out what edges are part of every path from x to y. Those are the bridges that will be invalidated by the addition of the edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow preprocessing, there is a fast method: Construct the [bridge-block forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)), whose vertices are 2-connected components, and whose edges are bridges. (It's a tree if the graph is connected.) When you add an edge, if this connects points in the same 2-connected component, nothing happens. If you connect points in different 2-connected components that were in different connected components of the bridge-block forest, then the new edge is a bridge (which you assume doesn't happen). If you connect two 2-connected components in the same connected component, then find the unique path of bridges between those 2-connected components. Those are no longer bridges, and all of the 2-connected components along the path are contracted to a new 2-connected component. Any bridge that is not along this path is still a bridge.

There is a comment stating that you eliminate at most one bridge. This is incorrect. You can connect any two points in the bridge-block forest, including points of arbitrary distance. Adding such an edge will eliminate arbitrarily many edges.

In your comments, you mention deleting edges. This might do nothing, but if you delete a non-bridge e, it might cause the 2-connected component C containing e to break into an arbitrarily long path, so you need to recompute the 2-connected components within C and replace C by this path of 2-connected components. The bridges connecting C to other 2-connected components become bridges connecting the new 2-connected components C_!, ..., C_k to the neighbors of C.

Comment: Contracting all of the 2-connected components along the path to a new 2-connected component is a potentially expensive operation if there are big CCs, because of the need to remap the 2-CC of all the nodes.

Comment: Good point. Updating the 2-connected components could mean c|V| updates.